# How to copy a directory using CMake in combination with a clean target?

Tags: cmake

How do I define a rule in CMake that will recursively copy a complete directory structure to a target directory, as well as remove the copied directory when running `make clean` afterwards?

Comment: By target you mean binary dir or install dir?

Comment: @arrowdodger, updated the question, hopefully it is clearer now.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/target_dir
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/dir ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/target_dir)
add_custom_target(copy_dir_target ALL
    DEPENDS ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/target_dir)
```

CMake should automatically add any files/dirs which are produced with OUTPUT of `add_custom_command()`.

If that wouldn't work you can try to gather files you wish to copy with `file(GLOB ...)`, then `add_custom_command()` which copies only single file with `foreach(FILE ${FILES})`, and finally wrap everthing into the single `add_custom_command()` call. This way every file will be cleaned, except of target dir itself.

Finally, you can play with setting `ADDITIONAL_MAKE_CLEAN_FILES` property on source dir, but be sure to copy files into respective binary dir.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that cleaning does not work, since it complains about the target directory not being empty.

As you stated, collecting files works, but does not clean up the directories itself. Still hoping for an easier, cleaner solution but I'm afraid it does not exist.

Comment: `The problem with this approach is that cleaning does not work, since it complains about the target directory not being empty.` Can you elaborate, please, on this?

Comment: The custom command generates a single output (the directory). The clean target tries to remove that single output, the directory. This fails, since it is not empty. I'm doubtful whether it would succeed even in case the directory is empty, since it probably executes `rm <directory>`, which will fail anyway.